# Terminating QProcess in a destructor

Tags: qt, qprocess

A have a problem trying to stop my `QProcess` in it's parent destructor. Here is my code:

```
AbstractProcess::~AbstractProcess()
{
    if((m_process->state() == QProcess::Running)
       || (m_process->state() == QProcess::Starting))
    {
        m_process->terminate();
        m_process->waitForFinished();
    }
}
```

`m_process` is a pointer to `QProcess`. In `AbstractProcess`'s constructor I have this code:

```
 m_process = new QProcess(this);
```

So, when `AbstractProcess` is deleted I get to it's destructor and I have a segmentation fault at :

```
m_process->waitForFinished();
```

Can anybody tell me what my mistake is?

**UPD**:
As was said below in the comments the problem was not in the code that I provided. Very sorry for that. So I will try to explain what the problem was. Maybe it will help somebody. `AbstractProcess` as you might guess by the name is an abstract class. So it has some pure virtual functions. On of them is:

```
virtual void onProcessFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus
exitStatus) = 0;
```

The full body of my constructor is:

```
m_process = new QProcess(this);
connect(m_process,static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
        this, &AbstractProcess::onProcessFinished);
```

And now it's obvious that on calling `waitForFinished` the process emits signal `finished` and the pure virtual function is called. That leads to undefined behaviour. To fix this I call `disconnect` before stopping my process. The destructor now looks like this:

```
AbstractProcess::~AbstractProcess()
{
    disconnect(m_process,static_cast<void(QProcess::*)(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished),
               this, &AbstractProcess::onProcessFinished)        
    if((m_process->state() == QProcess::Running)
       || (m_process->state() == QProcess::Starting))
    {
        m_process->terminate();
        m_process->waitForFinished();
    }
}
```

Thanx everybody for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to call `m_process->waitForFinished();` after attempt to terminate that process? It's not a `wait for terminated`, though.

Comment: @vahancho as far as I know after calling terminate I have to call waitForFinished to let the process finish all the job it has been doing.

Comment: @vahancho Any program should clean up any subprocesses it starts, namely do operating system's "wait" for it. using `waitForFinished` is one way to do that in Qt application (as long as you do it in a place or at a time where event loop hanging until process exits is ok).

Comment: @PolinaBodnar You should create a MCVE which duplicates the problem. As far as I can see (been a while since I coded similar things, though), the problem is not in the code you are showing. You probably have Undefined Behavior somewhere...

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code shown.  Can you provide a [mcve] if at all possible.

Comment: It is acceptable to answer your own question and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

When you call `m_process->terminate();` first, there is no guarantee that the process will **exit** .. yet there is no guarantee that the process will continue to **exist** because of calling (`WM_CLOSE` on windows / `SIGTERM` on Linux) so calling for `m_process->waitForFinished();` on a process that might have already been terminated might cause segmentation fault.
the right and safe approach is to do the right things in order:

```
  m_process->waitForFinished();
  m_process->terminate();
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm fairly certain that's incorrect.  Even if the child process has terminated the `QProcess` instance will maintain enough state that members such as `waitForFinished` can be called safely.

Comment: @G.M. OK, but It would be great to know the reference for your certainty because I don't find it in documentation.

Comment: [`waitForFinished`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp.html#_ZN8QProcess15waitForFinishedEi) checks the state of the process and returns false if the state is `QProcess::NotRunning`. And the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#details) say *When the process exits, QProcess reenters the NotRunning state (the initial state), and emits finished().* They also say about `waitForFinished`: *Returns true if the process finished; otherwise returns false (if the operation timed out, if an error occurred, or if this QProcess is already finished).*

Comment: Umm. waitForFinished blocks until process is terminated, so terminate is never called, so it will wait indefinitely... IOW the main application will hang.

Comment: @hyde, well thats true if _terminated_ means _finished ... as the doc says (_Returns true if the process finished; otherwise returns false (if the operation timed out, if an error occurred, or if this QProcess is already finished)._

Comment: @MohammadKanan Why would the process be already finished, if the premise of the question is "stop my QProcess in ... destructor"? Also, calling terminate after waitForFinished is still not useful (at least not in the code shown in this answer).

Comment: @hyde, if you look at the question ... the OP is checking for the process being either `QProcess::Running`  or `QProcess::Starting` ..nothing else, so the essence of checking for `waitForFinished()` before terminating ... or even not calling `terminate()` at all!

Comment: Of course terminated means finished. There is no special `terminated` state that leaves the `QProcess` object in some invalid state, which can cause segmentation faults. That would be terrible design.

Comment: @thuga, agree, in that case the OP just needs `waitForFinished()` .. with or without calling `terminate()` ... I don't see any issue calling `terminate`  after the process `finished()` ..  on the other hand things might not be under control if `terminate()` is called on a _starting_ process ... what would happen to the process resources?

Comment: Don't worry, this has been taken into the account by the Qt developers. It even [lets the process emit `started`/`errorOccurred`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qprocess.cpp.html#1134) if you kill it before it goes into `Running` state.